# Copy Folder recursively (including empty sub-folders) in MSBuild

Tags: .net, msbuild

I am trying to copy a folder recursively in MSBuild (excluding .svn folder) using the below target. It's working fine with the exception of folders which do not have any files. For example if there is an empty folder img under Src, img will not be copied over. Is there a way to copy empty folders as well?

```
<Target Name="CopyFolder">
    <ItemGroup>
        <SrcFolder Include="..\Src\**\*.*" 
                   Exclude="..\Src\**\.svn\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SrcFolder)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)\%(RecursiveDir)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Exec task calling xcopy or robocopy? Or some inline C# code?

Comment: I am expecting something in MSBuild.